# "Shot dead" v/s unfortunate or sudden demise

Tags: questions

Is it possible to use the word "shot dead" for unfortunate or sudden demise of a person not due to a gun shot?

Comment: _Shot dead_ can be redundant given a certain context.

Answer (score 4):

Shot dead signifies a shooting incident, be it a gun, crossbow, or even a cannon. There is no precedent to using it otherwise. You can use *struck down in their prime* or something like it if you want some short words instead of *unfortunate demise*.